# Code snippet not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, code-snippets

I'm trying to add a review snippet to a webpage after retrieving the corresponding data-id from the database. Unfortunatly the snippet doesn't work properly if I add the snippet like shown below. The snippet works fine if it is hardcoded in html but not if I add it in javascript or if I put the snippet without a data-id and then try to append the data-id attribute with the correct id.

I've tried loading my ajax call to the database in a script next to the div's location to then simply use `document.write()` but without success. The snippet in use is a review snippet from [Mobials](https://mobials.com/).

Help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="mobials"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.mobials.com/assets/js/api/v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mobials.com/assets/js/api/review.min.js"></script>


function Submit() {
        if (validateInputs()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@ViewBag.urlApi" +"LocationDetails?zipcode=" + $("#ZipCodeLoc").val() + "&format=JSON&authoriazation={"+"@ViewBag.ApiKey"+"}",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#events").empty();
                    $("#logos").empty();
                    $("#openingHours").empty();

                    locationDetails = JSON.parse(data);

                    //Customer Reviews
                    var isMobial = false;
                    $.each(locationDetails.Reviews, function (key, value) {
                        if(key == "Type" && value == 1){
                            isMobial = true;
                            $("#consumerAffairs").hide();
                        }
                        if(key == "ReviewCode" && isMobial){
                            var mob = document.getElementById("mobials");
                            mob.innerHTML += '<div class="mobials-root" data-id="'+value.reviewcode+'" data-language="en" data-type="badge" data-size="200"></div>';
                        }
                    });
            }};
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This line in my .html:

```
<div   class="mobials-root" data-id="someId" data-language="en" data-type="badge" data-size="200"></div>
```

Looks like this when loaded:

```
<div class="mobials-root" data-id="someId" data-language="en" data-type="badge" data-size="200" data-tracker="1" id="mobial-root-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mobials.com/api/badges/read_reviews/en/174_174_4.7_70.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `document.write()` with ajax calls.

`document.write()` will work "as expected" only as long as the document is *open*. As soon as the browser recognizes that the document is loaded completely, the document is *closed*.

Subsequent calls to `document.write()` will **replace** the document rather than append to it.

Edit: but looking at your code, I don't see `document.write()` at all.

Comment: I originally tried to use document.write but it didn't work. In the code above, I try to add the snippet throught the innerHTML method but it doesn't load properly. I can see the exact div I add with innerHTML once the page is in chrome but it doesn't load actual snippet in the UI.

Comment: @Marc-AndréViau with innerHTML=... it should work, in principle. Must be some other error somewhere. Can you shrink your code to some minimal assignment and then expand it again?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Marc-AndréViau well, what every debugging starts with: take your *big* code that doesn't work and skip some code until it does work, and/or create a very minimal code that at least gives some console log where expected and build it up. Somewhere between you will find the error. Sorry that I can't be more specific. My first answer was about document.write(), but you have excluded that point already and I can't spot the other one(s) easily.

Comment: I have since found the problem. It was related to the scripts that are loaded to make the snippet work. By creating them at the same time as I use create the actual snippet with innerHTML it solved my problem.